# Supporting different screens and Samsung s7 dpi

Tags: android, android-layout, samsung-mobile, screen-density

I've checked android's website about supporting multiple screens but I'm a little confused by dpi. I've a Samsung s7 (not the edge) and I test my app on it. I'm not sure if it's in the mdpi or hdpi group. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can use 
`float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;` in your app. 
and can check if the current device is mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi etc.
Here is [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) to official docs.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung s7 is of 1440x2560 resolution, which is a xxxhdpi device.
Normally,

```
hdpi: 480X800
xhdpi: 720X1280
xxhdpi: 1080X1920
xxxhdpi: 1440X2560
```

Comment: if s7 is xxxhdpi then what would a 10" tablet be like Samsung S2. When supporting multiple screens, would they both have a same pixel picture?

Comment: Screen resolution and screen sizes are two different things and are not related to each other. Screen density matters. 10" tablet can fall into mdpi also like Samsung Tab2. I believe Samsung S2 tab should be xxhdpi.